# Uploading assets to S3 using webpack

Tags: amazon-s3, webpack

Currently all images in my react project are being served by the nginx server. These images are bundles with source. The source does not use require/import but instead uses url paths to render the images.

Now I want to serve these images from cloudfront, using S3 as my storage.
I plan to create a set of assets on S3 for every environment.

I can think of two approaches for doing this:

**Approach 1. Using a script**

- create a script that runs after webpack bundling
- the script will upload files to S3
- paths in script and source will be deduced based on env variables

**Approach 2. Create a webpack loader**

- update source to import/require images
- create a loader that upload images to S3 and returns public path

Any opinions on these approaches or suggestions on a better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a webpack plugin that uploaded my static assets to S3.

I used a build parameter to deduce the base path of static assets in source and same param for deducing the upload path in plugin.